# Is there an easier way to stop at a breakpoint only when an error happens?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging

Is there an easier way to do this?
[image: Example]

Comment: If you want to only stop on errors on a breakpoint you need a spot that is actually executed when the exception happens so you need a catch or finally block. If you just want to stop on errors you might rather not use breakpoints at all but simply mark all exceptions as "Break when thrown" in the Exception Settings.

Comment: So I can't use a breakpoint to stop execution when an error happens?

Comment: You can set in exception settings (Debug > Windows > Exception Settings) to breack on "Common Language Runtime Exceptions". So if there is exception, the debuger will breack on the row that throw the exception. See [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/managing-exceptions-with-the-debugger?view=vs-2022)

Comment: You click in the left margin of your source code, you press "RUN" and when the error occurs, the application pauses. How do you want this to be easier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set breakpoint in [try catch](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch). The code in the catch will only be run when an error is encountered, otherwise it will be skipped.

Maybe you can set conditions in breakpoint:

1. Set breakpoint on the code.
2. Right click and choose Conditions.
3. Change the Conditions Expression like this:
   [image]

Comment: Why should `e` change here?

Comment: That's the functionality I want, but I shouldn't have to put the code into a try catch block, because it's annoying having to write code (haha). There should be an option to in the breakpoint settings for making it easier.

Comment: @Shiv-iwnl Hi, I changed my answer, if you think this method is not easy enough, you can also request a feature on [DC](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/VisualStudio/suggest).

Answer (score -1):

```
try
{
     // Your code here.
}
catch (Exception e)
{
     #if DEBUG         
     System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
     #endif
}
```